# Removing Users from MSOL Groups

Tags: powershell

I am trying to remove all disabled users from my MSOL groups within the company. There are roughly 50 users and I have already removed them from all the DLs an Shared Mailboxes, but I still need to have them taken off of the MSOL groups. I have written something fairly simple to do so;

```
$import = Import-Csv "C:\Users\Person\Desktop\DisabledMSOL.csv"

foreach($user in $import) {

$DisabledUserParams = @{

PersonID = $user.GroupID
ObjectId = $user.ObjectId
}

Remove-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $DisabledUserParams.ObjectId -GroupMemberType User -GroupmemberObjectId $DisabledUserParams.PersonID}
```

Problem is when I run this, it gives this error:

```
Remove-MsolGroupMember : Cannot bind parameter 'GroupMemberObjectId'. Cannot convert value "" to type "System.Guid"
Error: "Unrecognized Guid format."
At line:11 char:111
+ ... oupMemberType User -GroupmemberObjectId $DisabledUserParams.PersonID}
+                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-MsolGroupMember], 
ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.RemoveGroupMember
```

Please let me know what you think.

*Also, How do you make the yellow outline at this site? I have never really found out how to do so.

Thank you.

Comment: The `GroupMemberObjectId` wants a GUID. It seems in your CSV there is no value for `GroupID` (which you later translate into `$DisabledUserParams.PersonID`)

Comment: p.s. Read here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343635/how-to-compose-yellow-background-blockquote for the yellow outline

Comment: Thank you I i will take a look at it. Also I put the GUID for both the users and the MSOL groups in that CSV file. Is there an issue passing it through a splatter table?

Comment: No issue, but since you are not actually splatting i see no reason of translating the CSV values you could use directly. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6

Comment: I think you really need to show us what the CSV looks like..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it did not work was because there was an issue of misunderstanding the cmndlets in Exchange online and the syntax that is tied with it. I do not have an on Prem server and we do all Exchange online. Despite it correctly grabbing the GUIDs from the CSV, it was the wrong syntax:

```
Remove-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $DisabledUserParams.ObjectId -GroupMemberType User -GroupmemberObjectId $DisabledUserParams.PersonID}
```

The correct Syntax was:

```
Remove-RecipientPermission $DisabledUserParams.ObjectId -Trustee $DisabledUserParams.PersonID -AccessRights SendAs
```

For some reason the MSOL group came up as a mail group with only send as access; furthermore, it will only remove/add users using that syntax

```
Remove-RecipientPermission
```

Thank you for all your help though. I appreciate all the advice I get from this site.

Answer (score 0):

If you have about 50 records in the csv file and you get about 50 errors when you try to run your script, I'd double check those column/property names

If you try to access a property that doesn't exist, Powershell will silently continue.

[image]

If you get a partial success (some records work others don't), I'd check the values in the csv for the failures. You may think you have a `ObjectId` but may not.

Lastly, check your delimiter. If the csv file is tab or pipe delimited, you'll need to specify that delimiter in the `Import-Csv` call.

Good Luck!